# Siebel incremental backups to a non Siebel DB

Tags: oracle, azure, siebel

I have data in an Oracle Siebel data base and I want to move the data to the Azure Cloud over a VPN.

Is it possible to copy the database and then apply daily snapshots until I am ready to take the new Azure application live.

This reduces the risk of relying on a single big migration on the cutover weekend.

The destination DB is not Siebel, I will have to put the data into an Azure DB.

Just gathering ideas at the moment

Comment: I wonder if Azure has something like Amazon's Database Migration Service (DMS)? That might do the kind of thing you want.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by Azure DB? Is it Oracle database in Azure, MS SQL in Azure, or some other database (Cosmos, PostgreSQL etc)?